# Prove that every closed set in $R^n$ is the intersection of countable collection of open sets(proof-verification)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I saw only the proof by Lindelof Convering Theorem. But I have different arguments:

**My attempt:** Suppose $V = (v_1,v_2,...)$ is a collection of open sets and let's define point $p \in \cap V_i$. By definition intersection means, that $p \in V_i$ for $i = 1...n$. Also we know, that every point in $R$ is a limit point. Because $p \in V_i$ we can find $N_\epsilon(p)$ s.t $N \subset \cap V_i$ (Actually here I have proved, that intersection of finite collection of open sets are open).
Because $p$ is arbitrary and is a limit point => set $\cap V_i$ contains every limit point => set is closed

Comment: The intersection of a finite collection of open sets is open.

Comment: How can you "define" a point in the *intersection* of a given set of sets? If you prove the intersection is not empty then you can take a point there, but *not* "define it"...

Comment: finite --> countable makes it true, but this arument shows nothing.

Comment: I edited the title. Sorry for the missprint

Comment: @NateEldredge but isn't it true, that every point in $R$ is a limit point? I used this fact.

Comment: The phrase "is a limit point" by itself has no meaning.  You have to say "a limit point **of a particular set**."  It's true that every point in *R* is a limit point **of *R***.  That doesn't help you prove that it's a limit point **of *A***.

Comment: And now your argument is really wrong, because you when you write $V = \{V_1, \dots, V_n\}$ you are assuming that $V$ is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every subset $A$, the function $f:X \to \mathbb{R},f(x) = d(x,A) = \inf\{d(x,a): a \in A\} $ is continuous. This holds in all metric spaces.

A set $A$ is closed iff $d(x,A) = 0 \leftrightarrow x \in A$.

So for a closed $A = f^{-1}[\{0\}] = \cap_n f^{-1}[(-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})]$ 
is a $G_\delta$ in any metric space.

I don't know of any proof via Lindelöfness (a metric space or its closed subsets are Lindelöf iff they are separable), that seems restrictive.